# Convert unicode text to single byte ascii in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, ascii

I have an input file whose data I need to process. The file is in UTF-16 even though every single character in it is just a standard ascii character.

I can NOT change the input file so that it doesn't use useless double byte characters to represent 100% English language single character data. I need to convert this in python, on Windows. (Please, no non-python solutions, thank you).

I want my python program to act on these strings and output a file which is NOT double-byte. I just want standard ascii strings (one byte per character)

I've googled a lot, see all sorts of related questions, but not mine. I'm frustrated with not being able to solve this seemingly very simple question and need.

EDIT: Here is the program I got to work. It is absurd. There must be an easier way. The chr(10) references in the code is because the input has lines and I couldn't find a nonabsurd way to do simple readline/writeline calls.

```
with open('Unicode.txt','r') as input:
    with open('ASCII.txt','w') as output:
        for line in input.readlines():
            codelist=[code for code in line.encode('ascii','ignore') if code not in (0,10)]
            if codelist:
                output.write(''.join([chr(code) for code in codelist]+[chr(10)]))
```

Question solved after reading a hint from @Mark Ransom.

Comment: include sample code and whatever you have tried. default encoding in python 3 is UTF-8 if I am not wrong

Comment: A great many questions have been asked about converting Unicode to ASCII in Python (whether ignoring invalid characters, replacing them, or throwing an error). Can you explain how your question is different before this gets closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Josh As stated in the first line, every single character is just a standard ascii character, so you already have your answer about invalid characters. There are none.

Comment: @prateek, I just got a program to work, but needing to do this is absurd (my only complaint with python 3 after using it quite a while). I edited my question to include this absurd program.

Comment: @Josh My original post said "I've googled a lot, see all sorts of related questions, but not mine." If that is not precise enough, I spent many hours today reading lots of pages on stackoverflow trying to solve this. Maybe actually read my post before commenting. I spent a lot more time reading than you did.

Comment: The canonical way is to open the input with UTF-16 encoding and open the output with ASCII, and Python will convert everything automatically.

Comment: Then search again. You'll find the relevant introduction at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html, which should be enough to answer this question. Specifically, see _Reading and Writing Unicode Data_.

Comment: @Roeland: Typical holier-than-thou useless respondent on stackoverflow.

Your link has 4,517 words. The word ASCII is not in the title or in any headings or subheading. There are 24 instances of the word ASCII, only one of which is in a sentence with the word stem convert or some synonym of any word derived from the word stem convert.  That sentence was useless.

Comment: @Roeland: Instead of being holier-than-thou, you could have just written a short code example, if you could. I suppose you felt it was better to try to make the questioner feel foolish and have them waste a lot of time thinking your suggestion was useful.

Fortunately I was able to figure another angle from Mark Ransom's comment.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer, rather than including it in your question. There's nothing wrong with answering your own questions at SO.

Comment: @JeffWinchell OK my reply was quite harsh. Apologies for that. I still think that the linked article is useful. It doesn't literally tell you how to solve this question, but the information will help with a lot of problems related to these Unicode encodings.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('unicode.txt','r',encoding='UTF-16') as input:
    with open('ascii.txt','w',encoding='ascii') as output:
        output.write(input.read())
```

Comment: About as elegant as it gets, don't you think? I'm glad my hint was helpful, I didn't have time to make it an answer - and you did an awesome job with it.